# Menu appearing on other menu android

Tags: android

I am developing an app using actionbar sherlock. The problem I have is that I have the menus setup and all my xml files are correct since I get no compiler and logcat error.

THe problem I am having is that when I load a fragment A with its own specific menu everything is good. But when I then move to another fragment B, fragment A menu appears on fragment B. Any ideas as to whats causing this.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {      
    menu.clear();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);            
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.product_allergy, menu);


}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.productClear:
           addtoList(); 
        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu is belonged to Activty rather than fragments. Fragment A and B are in same activity, so when A adds some items into activity's menu and then it is replaced by Fragment B, the activity does not change, i.e., the menu is still there.

If you want your Fragment B to have different menu items, override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method, remember to `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in Fragment's `onCreate()` method.

FYI, if you simply want to clear prior fragment's menu item, call `menu.clear()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

**EDIT:**
When you are trying to handle the action bar callback in fragments, you should do something like below:

```
@override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.fragmentActionBarButton:
             //your code
             return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have all that code ..The fragment appears to be not receiving the callback on the action bar

Comment: In the fragment, you should check the selected item **BEFORE** you call `super.onOptionsItemSelected()`. See the edit.